# working with sequelize newCourse.setCategory is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am making a crud operation on courses where course and category has a m-t-m relation
my models are 2 separate files

course model

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = require('../database/connection')
const UserModel = require('./User')
const CategoryModel = require('./Category')

const Course = sequelize.define('Course', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    primaryKey: true,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV1
  },
  name: Sequelize.STRING(15),
  description: Sequelize.TEXT,
  points: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  image: Sequelize.STRING,
  createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
  updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE,
}, {
  tableName: 'courses'
})

Course.belongsToMany(UserModel, { through: "CoursesUsers" });
Course.belongsToMany(CategoryModel, { through: "CategoryCourses" });
CategoryModel.belongsToMany(Course, { through: "CategoryCourses"  });


module.exports = Course
```

category model

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = require('../database/connection')

const Category = sequelize.define('Category', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    primaryKey: true,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV1
  },
  name: Sequelize.STRING(15),
  createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
  updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE,
}, {
  tableName: 'categories'
})

module.exports = Category
```

categoryCourse model

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class CategoryCourse extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  };
  CategoryCourse.init({
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV1
    },
    courseId: DataTypes.UUID,
    categoryId: DataTypes.UUID
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'CategoryCourse',
  });
  return CategoryCourse;
};
```

in my controller i am creating new course then calling         `newCourse.setCategory(body.categories)`
to set categories but i am getting this error newCourse.setCategory is not a function

Comment: Take a look what methods newCourse has. Does it have setCategories or addCategories, for instance?

Comment: I was thinking about that but idk how to check methods it has
+ finding out if it is there or not wont help 
I know it is not there but idk why :/

Comment: You can set a breakpoint at the line you get newCourse and take a look at newCourse content

Comment: I did log it to the console and it doesn't have any set methods yet I have no clue why this is happening my model is working perfectly but the relation is broken

Comment: show a code where you create newCourse

Comment: I couldn't find a way to get the set method name so I started playing around with the setModel name until this worked .
newCourse.setCategories(body.categories)
guess it works like this model1.set(model2 plural)(......)